# How to create a horizontal repeater? And how to make a button be seen as an icon?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I am using a repeater control that shows data for some table. Each row in the repeater contains two columns: an icon (red/yellow/green circle) and an explanation.

I have to Goals, the first goal is to create the same repeater only now I need it to be horizontal. The second goal is that I need each icon (red/ green/ yellow circle) to be a button so that when I press on one of the icons, an event occurs (doesn't matter what, say Response.Write("Green is Pressed");

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it horizontal you can use the `li` list as `inline`, a css trick. The full code for that :

```
<head runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
    #navlist li
    {
        display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="navcontainer">
    <ul id="navlist">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>Some text and my id: <%# GetID(Container.DataItem) %></li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and on code behind:

```
public partial class Dokimes_StackOverFlow_HorizontialRepeater : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<int> oMainIds = new List<int>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            oMainIds.Add(i);
        }

        Repeater1.DataSource = oMainIds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }

    public int GetID(object oItem)
    {
        return (int)oItem;
    }
}
```

and you have a render like:

> Some text and my id: 0 Some text and my id: 1 Some text and my id: 2
>   Some text and my id: 3 Some text and my id: 4 Some text and my id: 5
>   Some text and my id: 6 Some text and my id: 7 Some text and my id: 8
>   Some text and my id: 9

Comment: I didn't quiet get the answer since I' new to this, especially CSS tricks :)
Guess I'll read some about <li> and things'll get clearer.
Thank you anyway for your help/

Comment: @Yanker I have write it with all the details, place it on a page and see it by your self.

Comment: As I said, I'll see it through based on your help as I'll dive into this. Thanks Aristos

Comment: I got it.. although I have to add an iconButton and some other stuff but now I got the idea. thanks so much (again)